# RSACryptoServiceProvider keysize 1024 is not generating a 128 byte key

Tags: c#, cryptography, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I have the following code:

```cs
byte[] rsaKey;

using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024))
{
    rsaKey = rsa.ExportCspBlob(false);
}
```

The result is that the length of `rsaKey` is **148** bytes and not **128**.

**Why is that?**

I have to pass the public key `rsaKey` to other system so the other system encrypts some data, then this data is going to be sent again to me.

**What key do I have to use to decrypt?**

Comment: Key has a length of 128 but ExportScpBlob exports all parameters which are needed to do encryption/decryption. Please look at struct  RSAParameters. I think that some of those data are also exported. Not only key.

Comment: @Hostel ok so those parameters are needed for the other system to encrypt with my public key right?

Comment: Yes, but keep in mind that you need export those parameters but not all. Only public key and parameters which are needed for operations related with pub key. Here you have some good examples: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider?view=netframework-4.8#examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key size for RSA is *not* the size of the encoded public key. The key size for asymmetric algorithms is a value that is directly related to the security strength. For RSA that is the size of the modulus, as factorization of the modulus is how you can attack RSA.

The public key consists of the modulus  of 128 bytes and a public exponent, so by definition it is already larger than the key size (although the public exponent is commonly just set to `0x010001` or 65537, the fifth prime of Fermat.

Add additional information for this *proprietary* Microsoft format and you get to 148 bytes. As 148 - 128 - 3 is 17, you expect 17 bytes of overhead.

---

To decrypt you've got to use the private key. I don't know why that isn't clear and what this has to do with the other question.